# Number of reduced fractions in terms of Euler's totient function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the number of reduced fractions $\frac{a}{b}$ with $1 \le a < b \le n$ in terms of Euler's totient function.

I was thinking that is should be of the form $\phi(1) + \phi(2) + \ldots + \phi(n)$, but i didn't know how to show it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $b=m$, $a$ must be between $1$ and $m$ and coprime with $m$, so for any fixed $b$ there are $\varphi(b)$ possibilities for $a$. The next step is to sum over the possible values of $b$, leading to:
$$ \varphi(1)+\varphi(2)+\ldots+\varphi(n) $$
as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct to do things properly, let :
$$A=\left\{\frac{a}{b}\big/ 0\leq a<b\leq n,\gcd(a,b)=1\right\}\\
 A_b=\left\{\frac{a}{b}\big/ 0\leq a<b,\gcd(a,b)=1\right\}$$

- The number of reduced fraction of dinomianotor $b$ is $|A_b|=\varphi(b)$
- We know that : $A=\cup_{b=1}^n A_b$ and $(A_b)_b$ are pairwise disjoint hence 
  $$|A|=|A_1|+|A_2|+\cdots+|A_n|=\sum_{i=1}^n\varphi(i) $$